# Will Facebook automatically use the V2.X of its API after the V1.0 is expired?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2, facebook-share

I am using below url for posting a link to the facebook :

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?.....
```

This URL automatically hits the V1.0 of the Facebook API.

And now as per the Facebook V1.0 will be gone in some time and only V2.X will remain.

Now I want to know that, is there a need to change the URL to

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/feed?
```

So that I can update the website before V1.0 gets away

Or it will automatically hit the V2.X after the V1.0 is expired.

Comment: Everything will default to v2.0 after v1.0 has fully expired in April.

Comment: Thanks Phillip, is there any official announcement for that ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/  - Second paragraph.

Comment: Link to the specific blog post (for future readers): https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/02/05/upgrade-to-v2-without-code-changes/

Answer (score 1):

Following URL Format :

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?.....

If you don't specify a versioning in an API call, the following rules will be applied :

- By default, if no versioning is specified in the URL. The oldest available version alive today will be used. But there are many special cases, see following bullet points. I quote :

> For APIs, once a version is no longer usable, any calls made to it will be defaulted to the next oldest usable version

- If your Facebook Application was created (and made at least one API call) before the current oldest version was released, The url will always use the oldest available version. **Example:** Let's say you created a Facebook application back when it was still 1.x, that url will call v1.x. After end of April 2015, this will be automatically v2.0 by default. Because v2.0 will be at that time the oldest available version.
- If you recently created a Facebook Application, the Facebook application will be automatically using the latest available version at the time of creation (and your first API call). **Example:** I created a Facebook application when v2.1 was the latest, but I never made a call with that Facebook API till v2.2 was released. The URL will use automatically version v2.2
- If you run on V1.x but you want to run already on v2.0, you can also enable in your Facebook application settings that by default you are now using v2.0. See https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YourAppId/settings/migrations/ -> "Use Graph API v2.0 by default"

Source of all this

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions#versioning